# make input field required whose correspond checkbox is checked

Tags: html, jquery

I am making a form where I am selecting only one checkbox from group of checkbox.
I want to make input field required whose corresponding checkbox are checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.check').click(function() {
    let name = $(this).attr("name")
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('.check[name="' + name + '"]').prop('required', false)
    } else {
      $('.check[name="' + name + '"]').prop('required', true)
    }
    $('.check[name="' + name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    <h5>A. Passport Number</h5>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    <h5>B. Voter ID Card</h5>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    <h5>C. Driving Licence</h5>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    <h5>D. NREGA Job Card</h5>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    <h5 class="d-inline">E. National Population Register Letter</h5>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    <h5 class="d-inline">F. Proof of Possession on Aadhaar</h5>
    <input type="text">
```

here I can only select one checkbox and make its corresponding text field required.
I want if I select nth checkbox then nth input field will mandatory to be filled.

Comment: if you want to select multiplie checkboxes, change their ids and name to be unique , ODV, ODV1, ODV2  ...

Comment: I don't want to select multiple checkbox. I want if I select first checkbox then first input field will mandatory to be filled.

Comment: Once you found your solution, pleas consider better structuring your form for the sake of semantics and accessibility. Every input needs a label assigned, and `<h5>` shouldn’t be used here if it’s not following a structure of `<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>`. A suggestion: `<label id="passport"><input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check">A. Passport Number</label>
    <input type="text" aria-labelledby="passport"><br>`

Comment: I also notice the required on your checkboxes. That doesn’t make sense to me. If it’s the user’s choice, why render them all mandatory?

Comment: it's not my full code I put only essential code. required in checkbox its not all mandatory any one of the following is mandatory you can run the code on console then you will understand what is happening here

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to 'link' the input to the corresponding checkboox. Group the corresponding controls in a `div`. This makes it easier to query the related inputs.

For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').click(function() {
        let name = $(this).attr("name")
        let text = $(this).siblings('input[type=text]').first()

        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('.check[name="' + name + '"]').prop('required', true)
            text.prop('required', true)
        } else {
            $('.check[name="' + name + '"]').prop('required', false)
            text.prop('required', false)
        }
        
        $('.check[name="' + name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false)
        $('.text').not(text).prop('required', false)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>

    <div>
        <h5>A. Passport Number</h5>
        <input type="text" class="text"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h5>B. Voter ID Card</h5>
        <input type="text" class="text"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h5>C. Driving Licence</h5>
        <input type="text" class="text"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h5>D. NREGA Job Card</h5>
        <input type="text" class="text"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h5 class="d-inline">E. National Population Register Letter</h5>
        <input type="text" class="text"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="OVD" name="OVD" class="check" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h5 class="d-inline">F. Proof of Possession on Aadhaar</h5>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: What is not working? The `required` attribute is added to the text input next to any checkbox you tick. It's also removed from the other text inputs when you select another checkbox.

Comment: you leave the first checkbox out of div & last div not have any checkbox. From your code when I select 2nd checkbox then it make 1st input field required. checkbox will be before h5 tag. don't change my jquery code because it affect my other portion of code which is connected to this code

Comment: That sounds like spaghetti... Maybe you'll have to refactor some bits to make this work. You can't do this by HTML only.